# Google chart HTML page integration in my existing project not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I have a google chart HTML page and it draws chart fine whenever I rut it individually.
the code of page is following

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
      <title>Value IQ</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css'>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700&display=swap' rel='stylesheet'>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- detail section start -->
    <section class='section-padding'>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-12'>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class='text-blue main-title'>Current v/s Previous year selling</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <!-- start:: Chart card -->
                    <div class='card-blk chart-card d-flex flex-column'>
                        <div class='card flex-grow-3'>
                            <div class='card-title'>
                                <h6 class='text-center'>
                                    Customers
                                </h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class='card-content text-center'>
                                <div id='chartElement3'>

<script type='text/javascript'>

google.charts.load('current', { 
callback: drawElement3Dashboard, 
'packages':['corechart', 'controls']
});

function drawElement3Dashboard() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string','customer_profile_value');
    data.addColumn('number','Current Turnover');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number','Last year Turnover');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addRows([['A+',19.9, '19.9', 18.2, '18.2'],['A',5.5, '5.5', 5.4, '5.4'],['B',2.4, '2.4', 2.3, '2.3'],['C',1.0, '1.0', 1.0, '1.0'],['C-',0.3, '0.3', 0.3, '0.3']]);
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div_3'));
    var controller = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter','containerId': 'filter_div_3','options': {'filterColumnLabel':'Current Turnover'}});
    var colChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({'chartType': 'ColumnChart','containerId': 'chart_div_3',
'options': {
    'height': 300,
'annotations': {'alwaysOutside': 'null','highContrast': 'true','textStyle': {'fontName': 'Times-Roman','fontSize': 9,'color': '#000000','opacity': 1}},
'legend' :{'position' :'bottom','alignment' :'center','element_legend_text' :'',},
'colors' :['#65A1DD','#9FC2EA','#919191','#CBCBCB','#E0E0E0','#717171','#C2D8F1'],
'enableInteractivity' :'true',
'forceIFrame' :'false',
'reverseCategories' :'false',
'tooltip' :'',
'slices' :'10',
'animation': { 'duration' :'2000',
'easing' :'linear',
'startup' :'true',
'alwaysOutside' :'',},
'bar': { 'groupWidth' :'61.8%',},
'hAxis': { 'direction':'1','format' :'short','gridlines': { 'count' :'-1','units' :'',},'logScale ':'false','scaleType' :'','textPosition' :'out','title' :'',},
'isStacked' :'false',
'orientation' :'horizontal',
'vAxis': { 'direction' :'1','format' :'short','gridlines': { 'count' :'4','units' :'',},'logScale' :'false','scaleType' :'','textPosition' :'out','title' :'','viewWindow':{'min':'0',}}
}});
    dashboard.bind(controller, colChart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
</script>

<div id='dashboard_div_3'>
                                        <div id='filter_div_3' style='display: none;'></div>
                                        <div id='chart_div_3'>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class='card-subtitle'>
                            User: Company name
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end:: Chart card -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Start:: Copyright and page text -->
            <div class='row mt-auto pt-3'>
                <div class='col-12'>
                    <div class='copyright-text d-flex justify-content-between'>
                        <span>Company Name</span>
                        <span>Page 1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End:: Copyright and page text -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- detail section end -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Now when I to put the content between  and  in particular  of my existing project page, chart is not drawn and in encounter following error in chrome's console

> VM410:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor at drawElement3Dashboard (eval at  (jquery-1.7.2.js:614), :7:13)

I already included

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
```

in my project.

JSfiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeet_bhatt/3eknfLab/1/)

Guys, what could be the cause of of this?

Comment: will you please share the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add this to your code.

you can place the callback directly in the load statement and you can depend on the callback to know when the page is ready.

```
google.charts.load('current', { 
    callback: drawElement3Dashboard, 
    'packages':['corechart', 'controls']
    });
```

Comment: But I already defined `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawElement3Dashboard);` in the page and is working fine as an individual page. Can you edit my html page and let me know how exactly I can change it plz?

Comment: Please create a Stackfiddle first.

Comment: Here it is - [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jeet_bhatt/3eknfLab/1/)

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that this HTML works correctly but whenever I add it's body part in my existing project, I'm getting the specified error. What could have caused such error. Any idea?

Comment: Updated the answer. check now.

Comment: It still gives error like - `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: google.visualization.DataTable is not a constructor
    at drawElement3Dashboard (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.7.2.js:614), <anonymous>:9:13)
    at loader.js:248`

Answer (score 0):

Check this by separating javascript and html

```js
google.charts.load('current', { 
callback: drawElement3Dashboard, 
'packages':['corechart', 'controls']
});

function drawElement3Dashboard() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string','customer_profile_value');
    data.addColumn('number','Current Turnover');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number','Last year Turnover');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addRows([['A+',19.9, '19.9', 18.2, '18.2'],['A',5.5, '5.5', 5.4, '5.4'],['B',2.4, '2.4', 2.3, '2.3'],['C',1.0, '1.0', 1.0, '1.0'],['C-',0.3, '0.3', 0.3, '0.3']]);
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div_3'));
    var controller = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter','containerId': 'filter_div_3','options': {'filterColumnLabel':'Current Turnover'}});
    var colChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({'chartType': 'ColumnChart','containerId': 'chart_div_3',
'options': {
    'height': 300,
'annotations': {'alwaysOutside': 'null','highContrast': 'true','textStyle': {'fontName': 'Times-Roman','fontSize': 9,'color': '#000000','opacity': 1}},
'legend' :{'position' :'bottom','alignment' :'center','element_legend_text' :'',},
'colors' :['#65A1DD','#9FC2EA','#919191','#CBCBCB','#E0E0E0','#717171','#C2D8F1'],
'enableInteractivity' :'true',
'forceIFrame' :'false',
'reverseCategories' :'false',
'tooltip' :'',
'slices' :'10',
'animation': { 'duration' :'2000',
'easing' :'linear',
'startup' :'true',
'alwaysOutside' :'',},
'bar': { 'groupWidth' :'61.8%',},
'hAxis': { 'direction':'1','format' :'short','gridlines': { 'count' :'-1','units' :'',},'logScale ':'false','scaleType' :'','textPosition' :'out','title' :'',},
'isStacked' :'false',
'orientation' :'horizontal',
'vAxis': { 'direction' :'1','format' :'short','gridlines': { 'count' :'4','units' :'',},'logScale' :'false','scaleType' :'','textPosition' :'out','title' :'','viewWindow':{'min':'0',}}
}});
    dashboard.bind(controller, colChart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
      <title>Value IQ</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css'>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700&display=swap' rel='stylesheet'>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- detail section start -->
    <section class='section-padding'>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-12'>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class='text-blue main-title'>Current v/s Previous year selling</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <!-- start:: Chart card -->
                    <div class='card-blk chart-card d-flex flex-column'>
                        <div class='card flex-grow-3'>
                            <div class='card-title'>
                                <h6 class='text-center'>
                                    Customers
                                </h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class='card-content text-center'>
                                <div id='chartElement3'>



<div id='dashboard_div_3'>
                                        <div id='filter_div_3' style='display: none;'></div>
                                        <div id='chart_div_3'>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class='card-subtitle'>
                            User: Company name
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end:: Chart card -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Start:: Copyright and page text -->
            <div class='row mt-auto pt-3'>
                <div class='col-12'>
                    <div class='copyright-text d-flex justify-content-between'>
                        <span>Company Name</span>
                        <span>Page 1</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End:: Copyright and page text -->
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- detail section end -->
   </body>
</html>
```